# PCIError filling my kern.log

Tags: kernel

I recently got warnings that `/var` was full (2 GB partition). The source is the kern.log filled with:

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.971746] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:a115] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.971747] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.971764] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.972426] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.972429] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.972434] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.972436] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:a115] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.972437] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Aug  7 15:36:48 laptop kernel: [ 9313.972440] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
```

I have an HP Pavilion 15 Gaming AK-100NF (i5 6300HQ, GTX 850M, 6 GB of RAM) with an added SSD (ubuntu is on it)

Here is the organisation of my SSD:

```
+-----+-+--+--------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------+
|SSD: | |  |                    |               |         |                         |
|33 GB| |  |     170 GB         |    18.63GB    | 12 GB   |        32 GB            |
|     | |  |                    |               |         |                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     | |  |     C:/            |   / (root)    | /swap   |       /home             |
+-----+-+--+--------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------+
```

The `/var` partition is on my HDD and is 2 GB

And here is the identification of the device:

```
$ sudo lspci -n          
00:00.0 0600: 8086:1910 (rev 07)
00:01.0 0604: 8086:1901 (rev 07)
00:02.0 0300: 8086:191b (rev 06)
00:04.0 1180: 8086:1903 (rev 07)
00:14.0 0c03: 8086:a12f (rev 31)
00:14.2 1180: 8086:a131 (rev 31)
00:16.0 0780: 8086:a13a (rev 31)
00:17.0 0106: 8086:a103 (rev 31)
00:1c.0 0604: 8086:a114 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 0604: 8086:a115 (rev f1) <----- device
00:1c.6 0604: 8086:a116 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 0601: 8086:a14e (rev 31)
00:1f.2 0580: 8086:a121 (rev 31)
00:1f.3 0403: 8086:a170 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 0c05: 8086:a123 (rev 31)
01:00.0 0302: 10de:139a (rev a2)
07:00.0 ff00: 10ec:522a (rev 01)
08:00.0 0280: 10ec:b723
09:00.0 0200: 10ec:8136 (rev 0a)

$ sudo lspci -s 00:1c.5  
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
```

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu LiveCD and try and clean out your /var on your /dev/sdaX partition. Hope that it isn't your SSD going bad.

Comment: I already cleaned it by typing `> /var/log/kern.log`. I'll try lscpi to identify the device, but I bought the SSD and the laptop a month ago, the SSD works fine under windows

Comment: Do you have a separate partition for /var? If so, you must have manually partitioned your Ubuntu disk, yes? Please describe. Post a gparted picture please. Also, put your swap on the HDD, not the SDD.

Comment: @heynnema I edited the post. Why no swap on SSD?

Comment: Edited again. Seems someone is getting the same error. Not resolved -_-

Comment: OK adding pci=nomsi works, tho I don't know why. Thanks anyway! What about the swap and SSD?

Comment: If you have a choice, don't put swap on the SSD because it reduces the lifespan of the SSD. Put it on the HDD. Also, why a separate /var on the HDD?? Whatever, it's obviously too small. Increase the 2GB partition that's there now... or... Move your 12GB swap to HDD and make it 6GB, and put /var where the 12GB space is now on your SSD.

Comment: So /var should be on SSD? Isn't writing going to reduce lifespan as well?

Comment: /var should be fine on the SSD, but, if you'd like to leave it on the HDD, just increase the size of the partition.